# Why [:][:1] don't work for list of tuples? How can I get iterable for a some index in all tuples in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I know how to match tuples in list. It's

```
a=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
if ('a','b','c') in a:
    print('it is')
```

But I need a partial match. ('a', 'b', 'j') should match ('a', 'b', 'c').
Maybe b[:2] for b in a?

Comment: How inexact can it be? You'll need to specify the exact rules you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to match the content which are in any **specific** sub-list *independent of the order of occurence*, you may use `all()` and `any()` with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> a=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
>>> match = ('a', 'c')  # Not together at `a[0]`

>>> any(all(m in b for m in match) for b in a)
True  # since ('a', 'c') are present at `a[0]`
```

If the *order* of the `match` list is to be considered, you may update the above code using *tuple slicing* as:

```
>>> match = ('b', 'c')  # together at `a[0]`
>>> any(match == b[i:i+len(match)] for b in a for i in range(len(b[:-len(match)+1])))
True  # since ('b', 'c') are present together at `a[0]`
```

Comment: That permits matching elements in the tuple to be in any order or position. That might not be what is requested. Another option is to match their prefixes: `any(match == b[:2] for b in a)`.

Comment: Thanks, Dan D, that is what I asked.

Comment: @ДенисКолесников: Then you need second part of the answer. If the elements are to be present at only `1`st and `2nd` index, use the expression Dan D. mentioned in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i'), ('a', 'b', 'j')]
to_match = ('a', 'b')
for item in a:
    if all(j in item for j in to_match):  # to check all the to_match element in the a list's element.
        print(item)
```

out:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'j')
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I need a little bit different thing.

```
[sc for sc in a if sc[:2] == ("a", "b")]
```

did it for me.

Comment: That is not ordered.